# Can my spouse accompany me to the U.K. without a visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, uk-citizens, visas-on-arrival, egyptian-citizens

I am a British Citizen and passport holder married to an Egyptian citizen with Egyptian passport.  We are both holders of the Spanish TIE card.  My question is, British citizens are allowed to travel to Spain without a visa so is the reverse true? Can we travel to the Uk for a short holiday without a visa ?  We shave been married for almost four years.  I know that I don’t need a visa but surely my spouse should be allowed to travel with me ?   It seems very unfair that British citizens can travel to the EU visa free, while I, a British citizen cannot travel to the country I was born in accompanied by my spouse without all the hassle and cost of obtaining a visa.  Surely our marriage certificate and return tickets is evidence that we have absolutely no intention of staying in the uk and  I understood that if traveling with me my spouse should be admitted but I have written to a number of British agencies and cannot get a definitive answer.  Can you help me ????

Comment: Things are never symmetric, and for sure you do not have the "TIE card" of Britain (but you are an UK citizen). And no: your wife needs a visa. There are simplified procedures for married people, but her citizenship matter. And by not living in UK, things are more difficult. Note: if you ask something, avoid to answer yourself with "Surely", etc.  Note the first result of first google search gave me: https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse. Do this answer your question?

Comment: "British citizens are allowed to travel to Spain without a visa so is the reverse true" - well, yes, Spanish citizens can travel to the UK without a visa, but your spouse isn't a Spanish citizen, so that's irrelevant.

Comment: *I, a British citizen cannot travel to the country I was born in accompanied by my spouse without all the hassle and cost of obtaining a visa.* - yes *you* can. Your spouse is another story. But, just FYI - there's absolutely no requirement that one would be allowed to the country they were born in without a visa.

Comment: Have you really not received "a definitive answer", or have you really only received (definitive) answers you don't like? I'm not busting your chops here - I feel your pain. I am the spouse of a UK citizen and would love to be able to visit my in-laws visa-free. We live in the USA (and I'm not American either) so up until recently I've been applying for (and receiving) 6-month visas every time we wanted to visit. We finally bit the bullet and got me a 10-year visa last year, so that at least makes planning travel a little easier.

Comment: I have received conflicting answers and contacted - or attempted to - and paid the fee they asked only to br told that they cannot comment in individual cases.  Thank you for your interest

Comment: can you re-phrase without the ranting, please? (which should go for not much longer than about this: can an Egyptian citizen married to a British citizen travel to the UK without a visa or with a visa on arrival?)

Comment: For what it's worth, for an Egyptian/Spanish couple who live outside the Schengen area, the Egyptian spouse _would also need a visa to fly to Spain together with the Spanish spouse_. Spain has indeed chosen to make it easier by applying EU free movement rules to family of its own citizens (so the visa is free of charge), but many countries have not -- including the UK when it was still in the EU. If you disagree with the UK's visa policy toward spouses of its citizens, the best venue for your rhetoric is the UK political arena: letters to newspapers, your MP, etc., not an international forum.

Comment: Still, I've upvoted the question.  Frequent users of this site are well versed in these matters, but we should remember that most of the world isn't, and other reasonable people will have the same question (especially if their travel experience has been trips to Europe when the UK was in the EU).

Answer (score 11):

Your spouse, an Egyptian citizen, requires a visa to enter the UK, even for a short visit, and even if accompanied by you, a UK citizen. Source: the UK government's [UK Visa Wizard](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

All the rest is politics and personal opinion.